# Show input box o if value from drop down menu is selected

Tags: php, javascript, forms

I'm working on a simple php contact form and struggling to get the "other" selection on the dropdown to show a text field option when it's selected. The form is included onto the page with `<?php require_once('includes/contact_form.php'); ?>` and the footer is also an include (the footer is where I have added the JS).

But it just wont work...

### Here is the Form:

```
<label>How did you hear about us?</label>
<select name="how" class="selectfield" id="how">
  <option value="">Please Select...</option>
  <option value="Advertisement">Advertisement</option>
  <option value="Care at Home Today">Care at Home Today</option>
  <option value="Email-Newsletter">Email/Newsletter</option>
  <option value="Facebook">Facebook</option>
  <option value="Family-Friend">Family or Friend</option>
  <option value="Magazine">Magazine Article</option>
  <option value="Twitter">Twitter</option>
  <option value="Website-Search Engine">Website/Search Engine</option>
  <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
<input type='text' id="other" class="hidden" />

<input name="contactus" type="submit" class="submit" id="contactus" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

### Here is the JS

```
$('#how').change(function(){
    var selected_item = $(this).val()
    if(selected_item == "other"){
        $('#other').val("").removeClass('hidden');
    }else{
        $('#other').val(selected_item).addClass('hidden');
    }
});
```

Comment: Not sure if it is a typo in the question but your dropdown value is "Other" and in your js you are testing for "other". So there is a mismatch. Might be your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it is a typo in the question but your dropdown value is "Other" and in your js you are testing for "other". So there is a mismatch. Might be your issue

Here is a working fiddle of your example just changing the "other" to "Other" in your if statement.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yUhtj/)

As coder1984 has suggested though, simply using jquery's `.show()` and `.hide()` in your if
statement would also work.

```
if(selected_item == "Other"){
    $('#other').val("").show()
}else{
    $('#other').val(selected_item).hide()
}
```

Comment: Hi all, thank you very much for your responses, much appreciated - it works a treat now.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('#how').change(function(){
var selected_item = $(this).val()
if(selected_item == "Other"){ // 'Other' 
    $('#other').val('').show(); //show textbox if Other is selected
}else{
    $('#other').hide(); //Hide textbox if anything else is selected
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in your string comparison, it should be:

```
 if(selected_item == "Other"){
```

With the Uppercase `O`, **Tested**